# How to add a null value as a byte manually using db.helper

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I am using the below code to manually insert data into a table 'Recipes' in an android app.

```
       MainActivity.dbHelper.insertRecipe("Steak",
                "rare steak","cook slowly","Prep time: 15 mins","Cooking time:20 mins","7.50",
               "Chef Special","Served with Rice","Chips",null );
```

> See below table schema

```
private int recipeID;
private String name;
private String description;
private String category;
private String ingredients;
private String prepTime;
private String cookTime;
private String difficulty;
private String servings;
private String method;
private byte[] image;
```

The null value is null because a blank picture will do in the application.. It is just for testing purposes. take no head of insert data info as i only want to test the insertion

When i run the application i get the below error

'the bind value at index 10 is null' so basically it isn't allow me to insert null as a byte value.

what can i insert instead of null that will successfully insert ?

Comment: How is the database table defined? Edit your question an post the schema

Comment: @DavidWasser is that what you are looking for ?

Comment: How is the table defined in the database? What are you using for a database? There is a way to declare that a column (field) in a database can be `null`